# Passing array to tableViewController.swift from viewController.swift

Tags: ios, swift4

I have created an array in viewController.swit class and trying to pass array to tableView in second class that is countrytableviewController.swift. I have passed array to countryArray that is working fine. But when i configured it in tableView methods and run the app. It is showing empty table.

**viewController.swift**

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destVC = segue.destination as! countryTableViewController
    destVC.countryArray = countryFlags

}
```

**countryTableViewController.swift**

```
class countryTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var countryArray = [String]()
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(countryArray)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return  countryArray.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = countryArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Show your tableviewController.swift code

Comment: I have posted code for both classes

Comment: You get the empty table because, you returned `numberOfSections` as 0. Change it to 1. ;-]

Comment: Thanks. Its working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `numberOfSections` method to `return 1` instead of `return 0`.